# Divergence of Chi-squared statistic

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I want to write "proof" that a ${\chi}^2$ statistic becomes larger and larger as the sample size increases. I have come up with the following:

For ${\chi}^2=\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{(O_j - E_j)^2}{E_j}\quad$    if   $\quad \Pr(\vert O_{j}-E_{j}\vert>0)=\epsilon\quad$ for $\quad\epsilon>0$ then

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{(O_j - E_j)^2}{E_j}\rightarrow \infty$ almost surely.

Is this enough and/or correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Some context may be helpful.  A $p$-value of what?  What are $O_j$ and $E_j$?  Do you want to prove the $p$-value is a decreasing function of $n$, or that it goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: $O_j$ are the observed values and $E_j$ are the expected values under the distribution we are testing against. I want to prove that the $p$-value tends to $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ which is equivalent to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{(O_j - E_j)^2}{E_j}\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @UltraEasy : A $p$-value is usually associated with a significance level for a null hypothesis. I don't see any reference to $\alpha $ . Hence the lack of clarity. Surely you have to fix $\alpha $?

Comment: @Benedict : The choice of $\alpha$ is irrelevant if $\alpha\neq0$ is it not? It is my understanding that the $p$-value will tend to $0$ since ${\chi}^2$ will tend to infinity as $n$ goes to infinity for all $\alpha\neq0$. Is this not the case?